# Make responsive button which includes text and a custom image

Tags: button, responsive

I need some help making a responsive button that includes both text and a custom image. It also needs to link to an external URL and I am trying to match it to an existing built-in button on the site.

I am using Wordpress, the theme is Vantage and the button that I am trying to match is a SiteOrigin button widget. The site is still under development but can be [found here](https://www.dominushosting.com.au/developer)

The button is in the Contact section at the bottom of the Home page and is the one with the words "Link to" and the image of the Broadmeadow Medical Centre on it. At the moment the button is just an image and it isn't responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.siteorigin-widget-tinymce.textwidget p{
    text-align:center;
}

@media (max-width: 780px){
    #panel-15-4-0-2> .panel-widget-style{
    width:100%;
    padding:0% !important;
    }

    .siteorigin-widget-tinymce.textwidget p a>img {
        width: 90%;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. That does work to reduce it and enlarge it on the various device sizes. Can I ask If there is a way to get it to exchange the image for a more correctly proportioned one for say a smaller layout and a larger layout? It's mainly the larger layout that is problematic.

Comment: possible option would be to use css property **background: url("images/image01.jpg")**

Comment: So, do you mean use the background property to call up a different version of the image at the different size in conjunction with the media query?

Comment: yes. setting the background along with media query and some padding would do the trick

Comment: Thanks, I will try it tomorrow. Cheers.

Comment: Hi VIX, I finally got around to trying what you said about using the css background property to add a different version of the image. And it worked… but I now have a problem of the other image appearing on top of that image. Another problem is that the new image is tiling when it appears (which might be rectified if I can remove the top image, which is defining the height it has to appear in)… Any suggestions?